# How to compare between to different JSON files and get result in new JSON file?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I am trying to collect two JSON files into one JSON file but the are completely different, but there are some elements are the same ex: NAME . So I want to get the different elements and add and but them with new Key name and do choose one element from the similar element I mean the Key!

And I tried to do it with this method:

```py
data = json.load(open("file1.json", encoding="utf-8-sig"))
data2 = json.load(open("file2.json", encoding="utf-8-sig"))
    for q in data :
        for d in data2:
            if d["web Name"]== q["Name"]:
                ALLDATA.append({
                        "name": q["Name"],
                        "rating":q["Rating"],
                        "addressf1": q["Address"],
                        "URLf2": d["URL"],

              })
                break
            else:
                pass
            pass
```

in name key I choose form which file I will get the value.
but the method give me error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/project/PycharmProjects/json work/testing.py", line 63, in <module>
    "addressf1": q["Address"],
KeyError: 'Address'
```

and when I try to print the address in the same loop it print it once and stop .

Comment: You're making us guess where the error is.  Edit the question to include the whole error traceback message.

Comment: Also, it would be nice to have a glance at how these 2 json files look like

Comment: There is (at least) one entry in file1.json that does not have an `Address` key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you John Gordon .

the problem was like what you said on your comment .

Thank to you all .

And i use this code to fill my JSON file with the missing key at every element:

```
finaldata=[]
data = json.load(open("file1.json", encoding="utf-8-sig"))
for item in data :
    if "Address" in item:
        finaldata.append(item)
        pass
    else:
        item["Address"]=None
        finaldata.append(item)
```